# When I tried to install opencv4nodejs I am getting an error

Tags: javascript, appium, nodejs

I  am new to `appium` using `javascript` and to install `appium` I am following this link [Setting up appium with javascript](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/appium-with-nodejs-for-automation-testing-of-android-applications/)

So when I installed appium-doctor and ran it I got an error.

```
info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.7.0
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node.EXE
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 8.11.3
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: 
C:\Users\Dbaux\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb exists at: 
C:\Users\Dbaux\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ android exists at: 
C:\Users\Dbaux\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ emulator exists at: 
C:\Users\Dbaux\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Bin directory of %JAVA_HOME% is set
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies completed, no 
fix needed. ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for optional dependencies starting ###
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ opencv4nodejs cannot be found.
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for optional dependencies completed, one 
fix needed. ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ### Optional Manual Fixes ###
info AppiumDoctor The configuration can install optionally. Please do the 
following manually:
WARN AppiumDoctor  ➜ Why opencv4nodejs is needed and how to install it is: 
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running- 
appium/image-comparison.md
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor Bye! Run appium-doctor again when all manual fixes have 
been applied!
info AppiumDoctor
```

From the above warning, I understood that I need to install `opencv4nodejs`.
So in `cmd`, I entered "npm I opencv4nodejs"

So when I entered that I got one more issue which I am not able to understand because it is telling me to install python which I don't know why?
Because I am using `javascript` to write the code why there is a need to install `python`.

```
> heapdump@0.3.12 install C:\Users\Dbaux\node_modules\heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Dbaux\node_modules\heapdump>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the 
PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Dbaux\node_modules\heapdump
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

> opencv-build@0.0.15 install C:\Users\Dbaux\node_modules\opencv-build
> node ./install.js

info install if you want to use an own OpenCV installation set 
OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD
info install library dir does not exist: C:\Users\Dbaux\node_modules\opencv-build\opencv\build\lib\Release
info install running install script...
ERR! Error: Command failed: cmake --version
'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dbaux\package.json'
npm WARN Dbaux No description
npm WARN Dbaux No repository field.
npm WARN Dbaux No README data
npm WARN Dbaux No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: heapdump@0.3.12 (node_modules\heapdump):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: heapdump@0.3.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! opencv-build@0.0.15 install: `node ./install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv-build@0.0.15 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dbaux\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12- 
26T09_56_55_948Z-debug.log
```

And please let me know if the documentation which I am following is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your error after running "appium-doctor"

- I will say please remove white spaces from all path which you are using. [Mandatory]
- I referred earlier [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs#how-to-install) to have correct installation for JavaScript. and all the things started working for me!

All the best!